# Does CSS scroll snap always break when resizing window?

Tags: css

I'm making a site where I'm using CSS scroll snap (vertically and horizontally). The scroll snap containers are variable (using vw and vh), and whenever I resize my browser window (Chrome) the snap positions go a little wonky, both the vertical and horizontal - [CodePen here](https://codepen.io/duvaljd/pen/oOJEjL).

HTML

```html
<div class='page-container'>
  <ul class='page-content'>
    <li class='section-container'>
      <header id="home">
        <div class="section-links">Side menu</div>
        <div class='section-content'>
          <div class='content-block'>
            <div class='content'>
              <h2>Scroll down</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    </li>
    <li class='section-container'>
      <section id='about' class='slideshow'>
        <ul class='section-links'>
          <li><a href='#1'>1</a></li>
          <li><a href='#2'>2</a></li>
          <li><a href='#3'>3</a></li>
          <li><a href='#4'>4</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class='section-content'>
          <div class='content-block slide' id='about-1'>
            <div class='content'>
              <p id='1'>First horizontal snap</p>
            </div>
          </div>

         <div class='content-block slide' id='about-2'>
          <div class='content'>
           <p id='2'>Second horizontal snap</p>
          </div>
         </div>

         <div class='content-block slide' id='about-3'>
          <div class='content'>
            <p id='3'>Third horizontal snap</p>
          </div>
         </div>

         <div class='content-block slide' id='about-4'>
          <div class='content'>
            <p id='4'>Fourth horizontal snap</p>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS

```css
html, body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 height: 100vh;
 min-height: 100%;
 width: 100vw;
 max-width: 100%;
 }

.page-container {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
 height: 100vh;
 overflow: hidden;
 }

.page-content {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #1C1E26;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
 scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
 scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
 scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100vh);
 }

.page-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
 visbility: hidden;
 display: none;
}

.section-container {
 scroll-snap-align: center;
}

section, header {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
 align-items: center;
 height: 100vh;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 10vh 10vw 0 10vw;
 }

.section-links {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column nowrap;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: flex-end;
 position: relative;
 min-width: 15vw;
 max-width: 200px;
 height: 70vh;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin-right: 5vw;
 }

.section-links:after {
 content:'';
 display: inline-flex;
 position: absolute;
 right: -19%;
 width: 0;
 height: 70vh;
 border: .5px dotted #fff;
 }

.section-content {
 display: flex;
 position: relative;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
 align-items: flex-start;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 height: 70vh;
 width: 55vw;
 max-width: 800px;
 overflow: auto;
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
 scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
 }

.section-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
 visbility: hidden;
 display: none;
 }

.content-block {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column nowrap;
 min-width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 scroll-snap-align: center;
 overflow-y: auto;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 padding-left: 1vw; /* For tab +/- signs*/
 }

.content {
 margin: auto 0;
 }
```

If you resize the frame of the codepen, or resize your browser window, you'll see what I mean -- vertically, the window gets stuck between two scroll snap positions, and horizontally, if you shrink and stretch the browser window, you'll see the scroll snap positions zoom across and once you release it also gets stuck between positions.

Is there any way (open to jquery and javacsript solutions) to force the snap positions to update after a window resize, so that they re-snap in the correct positions? Or would I just be better off using a jquery plugin or javascript until CSS scroll snap is a little more mature?